# Getting Installed App list with Duplicate Names

Tags: java, android

I read many blogs to fetch list of installed apps and tried there codes. But all codes are giving list of few unique apps. Though this list is long enough but repetitive names. Why I am not able to get entire list of apps.

The below code is giving me list of 224 apps with unique only 17.

```
  public class AppList extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    String TAG = "App List";
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.applistonly);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listforapps);

        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.

        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Log.i(TAG, "List Pack " + packages.size());

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(AppList.this, packages);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);

        }


    }





    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Activity activity;
        List<ApplicationInfo> applist;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        ListAdapter(Activity activity1, List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
            this.activity = activity1;
            this.applist = list;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            Log.i(TAG, "Adapter List " + applist.size());

            return applist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return applist.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView appname;
            private ImageView appimage;
            private CheckBox appsel;

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (layoutInflater == null) {
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            if (view == null) {
                //Custom list layout must be set
                assert layoutInflater != null;
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.applistcustom, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.appname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appname);
                viewHolder.appimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.appimage);
                viewHolder.appsel = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selapp);

            }
                //viewHolder.appname.setText(applist.get(i).packageName);


                viewHolder.appname.setText(applist.get(i).loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
                //    viewHolder.appname.setText(GetAppName(applist.get(i)));
                viewHolder.appimage.setImageDrawable(getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(applist.get(i)));



            return view;

        }


    }

}
```

pls guide where I m doing wrong as list size before sending to adapter is 224 and in list adapter on getcount it is 224. Then why list showing only 17 unique not with count of 224 instead of all 224 unique.

Comment: I tested your code, it show all app info in listview. On your side just show 17 items ? Could you describe more clearly your issue ?

Comment: yes it shows app but it is showing repetitive apps if u scroll the list you will find same names again and again in the listview multiple times

Comment: I recoded as per this http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/get-installed-application-in-list-view.html?m=1

Comment: Now working as per need.